# How to use SPEL to reference attribute of parameter in @GatewayHeader

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el, spelevaluationexception

This should be a simple question, but I cannot find the proper doc online.  I want to do this:

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "redemptionGateway", defaultRequestChannel = Channels.GATEWAY_OUTPUT, defaultHeaders = @GatewayHeader(name = "orderId", expression = "#redemption.orderId"))
public interface RedemptionGateway {
    void create(TrivialRedemption redemption);
}
```

I am obviously using the wrong statement to reference the `orderId` member of `redemption`:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'orderId' cannot be found on null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Look

```
@GatewayHeader(name = "orderId", expression = "#redemption.orderId")
```

This SpEL is evaluated at runtime against actual arguments to build `MessageHeaders` for target `Message` to send.

And that is how it looks:

```
private StandardEvaluationContext createMethodInvocationEvaluationContext(Object[] arguments) {
    StandardEvaluationContext context = ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(this.beanFactory);
    context.setVariable("args", arguments);

    context.setVariable("gatewayMethod", this.method);
    return context;
}
```

So, `EvaluationContext` is enriched with two variables `args`  and `gatewayMethod`.

As you see, there is no any arguments population by their name. Will that work anyway for all the JVMs?

You can achieve your goal using parameter index from the `args`:

```
expression = "#args[0].orderId"
```